# Gmail.js error: api.dom.email called with invalid element/id

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail.js

I'm attempting to create a Chrome extension to update the bodies of emails in an email thread. I'm following the [Gmail.js API Docs](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/tree/master#gmailnewgetemail_id), specifically this part about retrieving an:

> "object for interacting with an email currently present in the DOM"

I use the following code:

```
gmail.observe.on("load", () => {

  gmail.observe.on('view_thread', function(obj) {
    let threadId = gmail.new.get.thread_id()
    let threadData = gmail.new.get.thread_data(threadId)
    let emails = threadData.emails

    emails.forEach(function(email) {
        console.log(email.id)
        let emailObj = new gmail.dom.email(email.id)
        let body = emailObj.body()

        console.log(emailObj)
        console.log(body)
    })
  })
})
```

When I inspect the console, I see the following output:

[image: console output]

As you can see here, `emailObj` does not have any of the properties mentioned in the docs, such as `.body()`, since Gmail.js is throwing `api.dom.email called with invalid element/id`. However, as you can see from the output, the `email.id` is not null.

How can I properly use `gmail.dom.email`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/blob/master/src/gmail.js) for the library, it looks like `gmail.dom.email` is looking for an element with a [data-legacy-message-id] attribute matching the id you pass in.

(Lines 3547 ~ 3558)

```
api.dom.email = function(element) {
    if (this.constructor !== api.dom.email) {
        // if not invoked through new(), nothing works as expected!
        return new api.dom.email(element);
    }

    if (typeof element === "string") {
        this.id = element;
        element = $("div.adn[data-legacy-message-id='" + this.id + "']");
    } else {
        element = $(element);
    }
```

Given this, your code should work if you change your `let emailObj` line to:

```
let emailObj = new gmail.dom.email(email.legacy_email_id)
```

The function also accepts an element directly, so I believe the following will also work (where obj is the parameter passed into the view_thread handler).

```
let emailObj = gmail.dom.email(obj.$el.find("div.adn"))
```

Comment: As one of the main contributors to Gmail.JS this is definitely the right answer (at least for now).

A lot of work has been done to try to improve the ergonomics of the APIs with both these "new" style IDs and "legacy" style IDs (and the confusion that can cause), and I've been trying to make the API have as few "surprises" as possible.

That said, right now `api.dom.email` does not accept new style IDs in the constructor, so you will have to resort to legacy IDs instead. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: @JosteinKjønigsen and Kei thanks for the reply. This in combination with adding a wait time of 1sec before executing the code solved the problem. Is that a known issue? Maybe I shouldn't be trying to access this emailObj until a later observe event? `view_thread` seems like the best one though..

Comment: The ‘view_email’ event actually provides pre-made api.dom.email objects as event arguments. That’s probably the simplest.